# How to check if a library (libssh) is installed with Cmake before adding executable

Tags: cmake

I have an executable in cmake that depends on libssh being installed on the system.

I use this to install it:

sudo apt-get install -y libssh-dev

This is my Cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(validateTensor VERSION 0.0.1)

find_package(gflags QUIET)

add_executable(myapplication 
    "myapplication.cpp"
)

target_link_libraries(myapplication gflags teamApplication -lssh)
add_dependencies(myapplication teamApplication)
```

My question is how can I use cmake to check if libshh is installed on the system before adding the executable. If it is not installed then I want to exclude the executable from the build but not have the build fail.

Comment: Literally `find_library`. Do not use `-l` in `target_link_libraries`, just put the library. `target_link_libraries(... ssh)`.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks but I don't fully understand. Do you mean use `find_library` to check if libssh is installed? And it stores the result in a variable. But do I use an if statement for `target_link_libraries`? Would you have time to show an example?

Answer (score 2):

> How to check if a library (libssh) is installed with Cmake before adding executable

With `find_library`.

```
find_library(HAVE_SSH NAMES ssh)

add_executable(myapplication 
    myapplication.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(myapplication gflags teamApplication)
if (HAVE_SSH)
   target_link_libraries(myapplication ssh)
endif()
```

No need to `add_dependencies(myapplication teamApplication)` - `target_link_libraries` already "does that".